# Ruby on rails 5 uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9

I keep getting this error "/home/ubuntu/workspace/au5/app/models/user.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord (NameError)"

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and am following a tutorial on learning to create a sign/login page.

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
end
```

What am i doing wrong?

Code:

if you want to have a look the files can be find here

https://preview.c9users.io/salman15/consulegem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the `app/models/application_record.rb` file exists and that it has the following (or similar) code

```
# Base ApplicationRecord Class
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

If not, add it. It should have been generated by `rails new`.

Comment: Yes I've got it

Comment: Cloud9 has a Run option and shows me the error stated above

Comment: If it's not running the app through rails server or console you will get that error because rails has it own auto loading which might be the reason you get this error

Comment: It is running trough rails server